# Правописание притяжательных прилагательных от некоторых имён собственных

Tags: ономастика

У девочки Лизы есть щенок. Он Лизын или Лизин? По аналогии: Витын или Витин, если она – Вита? И самое главное – каким правилом это определяется?

Comment: В русском языке есть суффикс ИН/ЫН, причем орфографический вариант ЫН используется только после Ц. Во всех остальных случаях происходит замена твердого согласного на мягкий. Поэтому щенок Лизин, а варианты Вита - Витин и Витя - Витин различить нельзя. Это следует из грамматики (морфемики), другого правила здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**Лизин**, **Витин** (да, неясно, принадлежит мальчику Вите или девочке Вите - ну так и в дательном падеже, как видите, тоже неясно). Окончание *-ын* только после *Ц*: сестрица - сестрицын платок, курица - курицын дом.

Правила на -ИН, -ЫН не нашел, а примеры здесь:

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/29.htm  §39. Суффиксы имен прилагательных, п.13
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm  §164. Употребление притяжательных прилагательных